# Return Min-Max value of dates into one column with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the data shown below:

```
ID_DATA | DATE
--------------------
1101    | 2020-02-01
1101    | 2020-02-02
1101    | 2020-02-03
1102    | 2020-02-01
1102    | 2020-02-01
```

What I want is, under similar **ID_DATA**, there will be one column showing concatenated date range as string '**MIN(date) - MAX(date)**'. But if under similar **ID_DATA** the date is similar, it will only show the **DATE** as is.

Note that there might be more than 2 rows of **DATE** for a single **ID_DATA**. I'm hoping to use case-when.

Following expected result:

```
ID_DATA DATE
1101    2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03
1102    2020-02-01
```

Comment: This is not what you had asked earlier and not matching with the sample data and expected output. We need script of all the related tables to test the query whether it is passed in syntax check, running and giving the expected output.

Comment: Can you please help me to tell where to put the code,? As i only need ID_LIFTING and BL_DATE data from table C after joined as in the query.. i tried to put the case when based on that ID but always fails

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
SELECT
    ID_DATA,
    CONVERT(varchar, MIN(DATE), 111) +
        CASE WHEN MIN(DATE) < MAX(DATE)
             THEN ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar, MAX(DATE), 111)
             ELSE '' END AS DATE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID_DATA;
```

The logic here is use a `CASE` expression to check if the minimum date for an ID be smaller than the maximum date.  If so, then we display the upper range, otherwise we just report the minimum date.

Comment: hi @Tim I've tried but its showing error. I've posted my sample query above. Can you help how should I put your code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below using the `min()` and `max()` function.

```
WITH cte (
    ID_DATA
    ,MinDate
    ,MaxDate
    )
AS (
    SELECT ID_DATA
        ,Min(DtDATE) AS MinDate
        ,Max(DtDATE) AS MaxDate
    FROM TblData
    GROUP BY ID_DATA
    )
SELECT ID_DATA
    ,CASE 
        WHEN MinDate = MaxDate
            THEN Convert(VARCHAR(10), MinDate)
        ELSE Convert(VARCHAR(10), MinDate) + ' - ' + Convert(VARCHAR(10), MaxDate)
        END AS DatePeriod
FROM cte
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bfa062ac6e3649d01a5970e224d5218) demo.